# Adding shadow to the view

Tags: java, android

I have a view and I need to add shadow to it below and right. Here is my xml. 
With this xml, the borders at bottom and right look like a line rather than a shadow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/darkGray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/darkGray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="5px" android:right="5px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/lightGray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How can add shadow with the above code?

Comment: On the component using your layer-list (e.g. an ImageView), add `android:elevation="2dp"` (works only for API >= 21)

Comment: Stil doesnt work :(

Comment: What 'doesn't work' means? Can you please be more descriptive? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I works sorry..I was using in wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For shadow you can use elivation attributes in your view component. Check below show for show shadow in button :-

```
<Button
     android:elevation="5dp"/>
```